# How can I trigger shutdown or logout in KDE Plasma via QDbus in Python?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, dbus, kde-plasma

A KDE Plasma session can be given the signal to log out using the following in a terminal window:

```
qdbus6 org.kde.Shutdown /Shutdown org.kde.Shutdown.logout
```

or simply

```
qdbus6 org.kde.Shutdown /Shutdown logout
```

This immediately logs me out when I run it. Similar methods exist on the same Path for shutting down and restarting.

I would like to trigger the same thing from a Python script.

The QtDBus module in Qt enables sending messages over the DBus system. It is available in PySide6 and I am trying to send the exact same signal from Python:

```py
from PySide6.QtDBus import QDBusConnection, QDBusMessage

connection = QDBusConnection.sessionBus()
message = QDBusMessage.createTargetedSignal("org.kde.Shutdown", "/Shutdown", "org.kde.Shutdown", "logout")
print(connection.send(message))
```

If this code is run as a script, or entered into a Python interpreter, it returns `True`, but returns `False` if the script is run as root using `sudo`, which kind of implies to me that `org.kde.Shutdown` is available via the connection made with `sessionBus()` i.e. the connection is to the user session bus.

So why doesn't Plasma log out when I run the script?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The qdbus tool only ever calls methods. I cannot test this myself, but you probably need something more like this: `message = QDBusMessage.createMethodCall( 'org.kde.Shutdown', '/Shutdown', 'org.kde.Shutdown', 'logout'); connection.call(message)`.

Comment: Thanks, `QDMessage.createMethodCall()` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your qdbus command isn't sending a **signal**, it is sending a **method call.** They're distinct message types in D-Bus (and generally used in opposite ways – a typical signal would be sent "from" an object and interface that the *sender* has published; it is not directed towards any object at the recipient.) See [documentation](https://develop.kde.org/docs/features/d-bus/accessing_dbus_interfaces/).

Method calls always cause a reply, so you should send them using `call()` instead of `send()`.

Comment: Ah thanks, the similar syntax of `createTargetedSignal()` made me assume that's what I wanted and I hadn't clocked that there are both types of message.


As to your last point, once I use `message = QDBusMessage.createMethodCall()` it works with both `connection.send()` and `connection.call()`. The docs say that `send()`: "is suitable for errors, signals, and return values as well as calls whose return values are not necessary." So is it not fine to use in this application?

Comment: @matterhorn103: I don't know how send() handles a received message (the method_reply) that you don't consume; it might automatically discard it, but I would assume it might linger around in the program's memory (internal QDBus queue) forever – that would be fine for a one-off tool, but not something you want to accumulate over time. Using call(), on the other hand, should always pick up the received reply out of the queue and you can discard it in the usual ways.